# Changing Tomcat port from 8080 to 80

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I'm tring  to change tomcat's port from 8080 to 80. Until now, I'd a IIS running in port 80, without any problems. When I try to use 80 in 'conector' for Tomcat, the following error occours:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind '<'null'>':80 <!-- catalina's log
```

But IIS is disabled, and NETSTAT shows some connections with status TIME_WAIT for port 80. I'm a bit confused. How can IIS use port 80 and Tomcat doesn't? Should I configure another property?

Thanks!

(in time: tomcat 6 over win 2008 server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat is saying someone else is using port 80. `netstat -ao` will tell you which PID that is (look for local listeners, I am guessing most of those TIME_WAIT's are just browser hangovers), and Task Manager will let you work out which process that PID is.

Comment: I've located a machine on my intranet which opened the port 80 in my server. This machine is in another building, probably (even in another city, because its a big company). Can I force Tomcat to start in port 80 or bypass this check? (the process is in status TIME_WAIT, and the ports in client are 39694,41767 and 58595)

Comment: If port 80 on your machine is in use, it's in use, and Tomcat can't have it; and some process on your machine has it open - so you're going to have to end that process.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `server.xml` file and there find the `connector port` and just change the same port to 80 from 8080 and then restart the tomcat and fire the URL localhost:80 in your browser it will run the tomcat and will show the homepage of tomcat.